# Cancel WinRT ComboBox infinte scroll effect

Tags: winrt-xaml

How to cancel the infinite scroll effect on the ComboBox in WinRT. I tried a lot of solutions but no one seems working.

PS: I got this issue only in the touch mode !

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: Just a ComboBox with items !

Comment: And how many items? I've added a ComboBox with 12 items and there is no infinite scroll effect.

Comment: i forgot to precise that this effect is only in touch mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to `StackPanel`.

```
<ComboBox Width="200" Height="50">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Test"/>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968357/strange-behaviour-of-combobox-in-winrt

stackpanel causes some problems with item selection